# Hide connect string from OraConnection object

Tags: r, oracle, connection-string, roracle

When we create an Oracle connection in R with ROracle package, we create an "OraConnection" object. Usual command example:

```
connect = paste0("(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=yes) (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
          (HOST=", id$host, ") (PORT=", id$port, ")) 
          (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated) (SERVICE_NAME=", id$service, ")))")
con = ROracle::dbConnect(DBI::dbDriver("Oracle"), username = id$user, 
        password = id$pwd, dbname = connect)
```

Here, you well observe that I store IDs and connection information in an "id" R object (a dataframe actually) only viewable by the package but not by the user.
The purpose was to **not display this information to the end user**.

However, when the "con" object is created, if we call the object, all the information contained in "connect" object is displayed (see capture):
[OraConnection object display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4HDO.png)

[image]

My question is: **How could I hide the user name** (in blue in the image) **and the host and service names** (in red in the image) **in the "con" object**?

Unfortunatly, "OraConnection" object is not something from which I could drop attributes.

Comment: From a very quick search it looks like [ROracle supports Oracle Wallets and tnsnames.ora](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ROracle/versions/1.3-1/topics/dbConnect-methods) so you could investigate those?

Comment: @AlexPoole: I'm not sure to well understand the proposed approach. When they talk about a wallet for connection identifiers, does it mean the "tnsnames.ora" file? Actually, I know that if you specify the connection parameters in this file the "Connect String" of the "OraConnection" object will be replaces by the Oracle Base surname but I do not want that the end user of my R package (containing this connection function) have to edit a "tnsnames.ora" file since he mustn't access to the identifiers.

Comment: maybe u can create a env `.pkgenv <- new.env()` and then assign your `id` and `con` to this `.pkgenv` within your `.onAttach`/`.onLoad` functions? When the variable name starts with a dot, the user is unable to access it.